# Google AppEngine (Java) Memcache not storing data

Tags: java, google-app-engine, memcached, jcache

I have this code

```
//net.sf.jsr107cache.Cache, CacheException, CacheFactory, CacheManager all imported
private static Cache getCache() {

    Cache cache = null;
    try {
        CacheFactory cacheFactory = CacheManager.getInstance().getCacheFactory();
        cache = cacheFactory.createCache(Collections.emptyMap());
    } catch (CacheException e) {
        Logger.getLogger(MemcacheUtil.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, 
                "Unable to obtain a cache instance! \n" + e.getMessage());
    }
    return cache;
}
```

and use it like this

```
public static byte[] fetchFromMemcache(String key) {
    return (byte[]) getCache().get(key);
}

public static void saveInMemcache(String key, byte[] value) {
    getCache().put(key, value);
}
```

but annoyingly, nothing gets stored in Memcache and no log message gets printed. Before implementing caching with JCache, I used the Low-level API and had the same problem too. I'm really confused. Is there any special setting (in code, on the appengine console, etc) that needs to be done before Memcache works? Does Memcache just hate me naturally? Is there something I'm doing (or failing to do) in code that's causing all these? Please I'll like to know how to go about this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no special setting (in code or on the appengine console) that needs to be set before Memcache can be used using the low-level API.

I use this API without problem.

(If you want, tomorrow I can give you code that I use to exchange data with the memcache successfully.

Comment: Please let me know if the other answer does not suffice for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of a class providing static methods to write/read from the Memcache with the low-level API.
The advantage is that I use a singleton instance of the cache, providing better response times. You are creating new instances of the factory and the cache service for each request, what is basically not a good idea.

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheService;
import com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServiceFactory;
import com.google.appengine.api.memcache.Stats;


public class AppMemCache {
private static MemcacheService c = MemcacheServiceFactory.getMemcacheService();

public static boolean containsKey(Object key){
    return c.contains(key);
}


public static Object get(Object key){
    return c.get(key);
}

// returns only the cached key/object pairs 
public static Map<String, Object> getAll(Collection<String> keys){
    return c.getAll(keys);
}

public static void put(Object key, Object value){
    c.put(key, value);
}


public static void putAll( Map<String, Object> values){
    c.putAll(values);
}

public static boolean remove(Object key){
    return c.delete(key);
}

@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
public static boolean deleteAll(Collection keys){
    Set deletedKeys = c.deleteAll(keys);
    if(deletedKeys.size() == keys.size())
        return true;
    return false;
}

public static Stats getStatistics(){
    return c.getStatistics();
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm going to try out this code ASAP. By the way, I was also doing something like this before, I reverted to getting cache instances every time as a result of frustration. Meanwhile the code I posted above uses JCache (a high-level API) while, your answer uses the com.google.appengine (low-level API) directly. I was also using this and only reverted to JCache when it didn't work. I'll give your code a spin exactly as it is and report here if it works or not. Thanks!